How to upload a startup script from a bucket using Terraform?
I need to upload a startup script from a bucket in Cloud Storage using Terraform. Service account has appropriate permissions.
I tried 3 different ways:

main:
module "instance_template" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/vm/google//modules/instance_template"
  version = "~> 11.0"



    name_prefix         = var.name_prefix
      project_id          = var.project
      machine_type        = var.machine_type
      disk_size_gb        = var.disk_size_gb
      disk_type           = var.disk_type
      disk_labels         = var.disk_labels
      subnetwork          = var.subnet
      subnetwork_project  = var.host_project
      additional_networks = var.additional_networks
      region              = var.region
      startup_script      = var.startup_script_url

variables:
variable "startup_script_url" {
  type = string

  description = "Render a startup script with a template."
  default     = "gs://bucketbbbb/script.sh"
}


...
module "instance_template" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/vm/google//modules/instance_template"
  version = "~> 11.0"

  name_prefix         = var.name_prefix
  project_id          = var.project
  machine_type        = var.machine_type
  disk_size_gb        = var.disk_size_gb
  disk_type           = var.disk_type
  disk_labels         = var.disk_labels
  subnetwork          = var.subnet
  subnetwork_project  = var.host_project
  additional_networks = var.additional_networks
  region              = var.region


  service_account = {
    email  = local.service_account_email
    scopes = var.scopes
  }
  enable_shielded_vm   = var.shielded_vm
  source_image         = var.image
  source_image_family  = var.image_family
  source_image_project = var.image_project
  preemptible          = var.preemptible
  can_ip_forward       = var.can_ip_forward ? "true" : "false"

  tags   = var.tags
  labels = var.labels

  metadata = merge(
    var.metadata,
    {

      //enable-oslogin = "TRUE",
      //startup-script-url = "gs://bucketbbbb/script.sh",

    }
  )
}


...
 resource "google_compute_instance_from_template" "bastion_vm" {
      count   = var.create_instance_from_template ? 1 : 0
      name    = var.name
      project = var.project
      zone    = var.zone
      labels  = var.labels

      metadata = {
        startup-script-url = "gs://bucketbbbb/script.sh"
      }



And none of them work. If I add the startup script manually in Google Console everything works fine, but when I try to add it with Terraform it won't.
Permissions for service account:
    variable "service_account_roles_supplemental" {
      type        = list(string)
      description = "An additional list of roles to assign to the bastion if desired"
      default     = [
        "roles/storage.legacyObjectReader",
        "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader",
      ]
    }

EDIT: sorry that the code is edited so badly, Stack won't show some parts of the code as code even when i mark it as a whole

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

When you share what you already tried it's important to also share what result you saw when you tried that. "None of them work" unfortunately isn't enough information to start thinking about what might be going on. Would you edit your question to also include information about what happened for each individual attempt, including the full text of any error messages Terraform returned, or whatever other information you used to determine that it hadn't worked. Thanks!

I've got no errors, everything is running correctly except for the part with startup script. How do I know it is not working? The startup script contains commands installing git, jq and couple more, when I connect to the vm and try the git command I get the "git command not recognized" alert, which means git is not installed, which means startup script did not run. When i add the script manually with google console everything works, so there are no problems with the script itself.
